# Can a once-firing trigger be used to reduce data volume

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Datasets:

`user: user_id, nice_id
clicks: click_id, user_id, page_id, time
pages: page_id, page_name
output_clicks: click_id, user_nice_id, page_name, time`

The user, clicks, and pages pcollections are all unbounded. new versions of users come in with new names, but their nice_id never changes, new versions of pages come in with new page_names, clicks never change, but we would like a new output_click if the page_name of a click changes.

So there's a CoGroupByKey between clicks and pages on page_id with a Global window that triggers on every input element, and re-emits every click for that page, but if I have a similar Global window and co-group-by-key on user_id and emits every click with the nice_id on every element then we'll get all the clicks for a user re-emitted whenever that user changes, or whenever they make a new click. That's going to be a lot of extra data.

What I'm thinking is after the co-group-by-key on user_id, have a group-by-key on click_id, a new global window with a trigger that only fires once, a ParDo that does essentially nothing so that the group-by-key happens, then re-establish the global window that fires on every element before joining back to the output of the result of the co-group-by-key on page_id. This seems like it would work? But also seems... more than a bit convoluted. I've tried to draw a diagram below.

`+-------+   +--------+     +------+
|Pages  |   | Clicks |     | Users|
+---+---+   +---+----+     +--+---+
    |           |             |
+---v----+  +---v----+    +---v----+
|R.Window|  |R.Window|    |R.Window|
+------+-+ +---------+    ++-------+
       |   |         |     |
  +----v---v+       +v-----v---+
  |CoGroupBy|       |CoGroupBy |
  |page_id  |       |user_id   |<-- also ParDo that outputs click_id,nice_id mapping
  +-------+-+       +------+---+
          |                |
          |            +---v----+
          |            |O.Window|
          |            +---+----+
          |                |
          |           +----v---+
          |           |GroupBy |
          |           |click_id|
          |           +----+---+
          |                |
          |           +----v--+
          |           |nothing|
          |           |Pardo  |
          |           +---+---+
          |               |
          |          +----v---+
          |          |R.Window|
          |          +-+------+
          |            |
      +---v------------v+
      |   CoGroupBy     |
      |   click_id      |
      +-------+---------+
              |
              v
           Output`

R.Window = Global window with trigger that fires repeatedly on new data
O.Window = Global window with trigger that fires only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will quite work; the first thing that comes through CoGroupByUserId for a key will get through, but all subsequent records will be dropped.

Instead of using CoGroupByKey, I would recommend using Flatten and CombinePerKey with a custom CombineFn.  That CombineFn will keep state in the accumulator (make sure to use .accumulatingFiredPanes on your Window transform), and then can can choose to only emit elements when there is a new user name.

(Side note: you don't need the "nothing ParDo"; just the GBK is enough)

Comment: I abbreviated a little, I perhaps shouldn't have. There's a ParDo after the CoGroupByUserId that only emits records where both the user and the click are present. Also, we don't use the user_name, we're joining to user to ge the nice_id, and there's no such thing as a "new" nice_id. A user's nice_id is constant, and a click's user can never change.

Comment: Also I don't think all subsequent records will be dropped, only all subsequent records per *audit_id* right?

Comment: I'll have to read up on CombinePerKey and CombineFn again, I didn't realise there was a way to use them to remove duplicates/unnecessary updates like that. Would that be a potential answer to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/64043061?noredirect=1 ?

Comment: Yeah, CombineFn can be used to keep state for this sort of thing, although it's not the most natural API.  If your curious about future directions here, you can follow https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-23

Comment: Is there any documentation of how CombineFn can be used to keep state for this? Is the idea that you can modify the accumulator state when extractOutput is called?

Comment: It's not documented, since the new state API is really the right way to do this.  The basic idea is that if you are triggering on every element, the accumulator can assume that it will always be output from at each stage and have a bit of whether or not to produce anything; then a downstream DoFn can trivially filter out the empty records

Comment: I don't understand the mechanism of what you're saying, is it that you *can* update AccumT inside the extractOutput method? In this thread it was said we can't do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234741/remove-duplicates-across-window-triggers-firings?noredirect=1#comment64043061_38234741 , and in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297821/detecting-keyed-state-changes , and now you're saying that you can, but it's not documented, because of a coming state API. Which is fine, but while waiting for the state API I need a way to join data without exploding resource usage

Comment: You can't update the accumulator from extract.  However, the accumulator can keep track of whether the last element added should cause an element to be emitted.  If that is true, extractOutput will return a real value, and if not, a dummy value.  You can then combine this with a trigger that fires on every element, and a DoFn that drops the dummy elements.  The trigger firings should end up relatively cheap due to caching in the workers, and the downstream processing will only have to deal with the data you want

Comment: Ahhhhh you can use the Accumulator as a way to establish order, what was the last thing that happened, similar to what I was thinking back here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324879/is-the-iterable-created-by-groupbykey-ordered/35326127#35326127 it should have occurred to me that I could do that. Thanks daniel

Comment: wait... wouldn't that require `accums` in mergeAccumulators to be ordered? otherwise we don't know if it's the Accum from this element coming in, or the Accum from a previous fire

Comment: Or tag the result of mergeAccumulators with the time they happened and just be a bit heuristical about whether an extractOutput is likely to have happened in that amount of time? I'm going to go with that for now

Comment: Ok no while I was tired that seemed to make sense. Now I'm back to "what happens if an element that should cause an emit, and an element that shouldn't arrive at the same time". there's no way to know whether an accumulator value is from a previous firing and has already been extractOutput'd, or whether it's part of this firing. At least as far as I can see right now